# Pattern Matcher Android Split a String

Tags: java, android, pattern-matching

Problem Statement: I want to read the USSD codes in the background and want to fetch some values:

E.g

1. Your data balance left is 400 MB, validity is 20 APR 2017. (need to extract '400 MB')
2. Your data balance left is 0.04 GB, validity is 20 APR 2017. (I need to extract 0.04 GB)

and so on...

How can I ? Can anyone please help. How can I do these types of splits

Comment: should your "pattern" match between **left is** and **,** ('left is' and a comma) or the text is just an example...??

Comment: @ΦXocę웃ПepeúpaツThis text is an example. Any string can come, but I want to extract data balance only

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your crawler is geting the same info msga but for sure you can use regex to match the info you need...

```
String str = "Your data balance left is 400 MB, validity is 20 APR 2017. (need to extract '400 MB')\n"
            + "Your data balance left is 0.04 GB, validity is 20 APR 2017. (I need to extract 0.04 GB)";

Matcher myMatcher = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("left is") + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(", validity is"))
            .matcher(str);
while (myMatcher.find()) {
     String result = myMatcher.group(1).trim();
     String[] spltter = result.split(" ");
     System.out.println("result: " + result);
     System.out.println("value: " + spltter[0]);
     System.out.println("result: " + spltter[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to extract what you are looking for, it does not need any pattern matcher class

```
 private String ussdString = "Your data balance left is 400 MB, validity is 20 APR 2017";
 String[] stringArray = ussdString.split(",");
        String ussdStringData = stringArray[0];
        ussdStringData = ussdStringData.replace("Your data balance left is ", "");
        System.out.println("Data is " + ussdStringData);
```

Simple solution for it